# Can i prevent users from creating user notification on our SitePages library

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, modern-pages, notifications

Currently when users set a user notification on the "SitePages" library, to send email notifications directly,as follow:-

[image]

they will receive emails which contain random page names such as `wuwusoj2818.aspx`. i read about this problem and seems when creating modern pages, sharepoint will assign it a random name and at that time a user notification will be sent, before even saving the page or give it a title/name.

now i find a workaround to fix this issue, where i want to  delete all the user notifications + write a workflow which will send am email to the users , instead of relying on the user notifications.

but i am not sure if there is a way to disable creating user notifications on the SitePages list? to prevent end users from creating user notifications on the SitePages library?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This may not be possible. By default, all lists and libraries have their default "Alert me" and "Manage my alerts" section.

Even if you somehow disable/hide by CSS in the SitePages library, users would still be able to create them by navigating to "Manage my alerts" page.

So I wouldn't spend my time in implementing CSS to close all the loops for creating user notifications, rather advise the users that the experience of user notification has certain limitations. This should be part of your communication strategy.

Comment: yes i am planning to inform the users not to set user notifications on SitePages (mainly modern site pages), but i was asking if i can disable this option on the SitePages libraries.... seems it is not possible through for example changing a setting on the library, even defining css will not work on modern experience which we are using..